# in htacess how to rewrite rule when user types domain name only?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
#when the user types the domain name only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^$
RewriteRule . /index2.php [L]
```

my goal is to run `index2.php` when the user types only the doman name in the browser address bar. That code does not seem to work however.

I have also tried other variations without success:

```
#when the user types the domain name only
RewriteCond ! %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
RewriteRule . /index2.php [L]
```

And

```
 RewriteRule ^/$ /index2.php [L]
```

Comment: This sounds like you shouldn't be handling it with mod_rewrite. Instead this would be handled with `DirectoryIndex  index2.php` to make `index2.php` the default file. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: so, there is no way of doing it without the DIrectoryIndex?

Comment: @user2070775 Why can't you use DirectoryIndex? That's the purpose of DirectoryIndex to use the specified file as the default index file. Is there another reason you need to do that?

Comment: You could do it with mod_rewrite, but it seems needlessly complex.  With no `RewriteCond`, it ought to work merely with `RewriteRule ^$ index2.php [L]` in the root .htaccess.  Your `^/$` doesn't work because .htaccess operates in directory context and doesn't include a leading `/` on the URI.  This is the specific job of `DirectoryIndex` though.

Comment: @PanamaJack you are right.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski YES!! It worked when I changed it to ^$. Man, that was simple enough!

Comment: @user2070775 FYI, there are multiple ways to accomplish things in Apache, which make it powerful, however there are some builtin functions that are made for specific tasks and `DirectoryIndex` is one of those. Good Luck

Comment: You guys are awesome. I love you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a rewrite rule for this. Just use this line in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```